# AWS SES Setup with Django

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, django-ses

I am trying to add AWS SES into my project. Where I get a different region listed

```
MessageRejected at /
An error occurred (MessageRejected) when calling the SendRawEmail operation: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-EAST-1: email@hotmail.com
```

In the AWS verified identities it is listed:

```
email@hotmail.com   Email address   Verified
```

I have the permissions for the SES for my policy for that user.

```
Attached from group
 AmazonSESFullAccess
AWS managed policy from group AmazonSESFullAccess
```

Also my settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_ses.SESBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
```

Where it's used

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings

 send_mail(email_subject, email_message,'email@hotmail.com',['email@hotmail.com'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Amazon SES sandbox**

I'm assuming you're in Sandbox mode, which means you need to add the recipients' email addresses to successfully send the email. You can make a request to exit sandbox mode, then the daily limit of sent emails will increase and you will not have to define them.

More on this topic can be found here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/request-production-access.html

**2. New settings with TLS**

The second option is to check if the mail works with TLC settings:

Example settings:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'email-smtp.<your AWS region>.amazonaws.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'smtp_username'.     # IAM user SMTP Credentials
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'smtp_password'  # IAM user SMTP Credentials
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'my@mail.com'     # You need to verify this mail
```